# Website - Keeps reverting back to old version after changes have been made?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I've created my website using HTML, CSS, Javascript, Bootstrap and PHP. Now I created a basic website and I decided to change a few things on it. So I have done this by opening up Notepad++ and changing things like spelling and glyphicons and then I save the changes and then click run in Notepad++ and all is great in the browser. Changes applied successfully. Then I go back to my folder and open with either chrome, IE or firefox and again great the change was successful.

Though as soon as I click on a tab to got to another newly changed page the changes aren't there and it's reverted back to an older version. Then I'll click to go back to the page I was just on and it will have one or two of the features I've just changed but the rest has reverted.

But if I go back into the folder or Notepad++ and run the index.html or about.html file then it's fine again until I navigate the pages then it starts reverting back.

I need help as this is such a pain and I have no idea why it's not just updating?

Any questions please just ask. Been at this for three days!

Comment: is this website local or hosted? Are you sure you are saving pages?  Saving them in the correct location?

Comment: have you updated the index.html file or the php included elements?

Comment: Are you seeing the cached versions of the pages? Have you tried hard-refreshing the pages with CTRL+F5?

Comment: The website was hosted but I took it down due to these issues so it's local at the moment and I've even tried overwriting the file to make sure it's been saved but that has as much success as simply hitting the save button. And it's only the index file that I've updated but I'm trying to change things like spelling in paragraphs and symbols or menu headings so I don't see why the php which is barley utilised would cause any problems.

Comment: Yes and on my only working page CTRL+F5 actually reverts it to an old version :)

Comment: are you sure you aren't linking to a different version when you click on links? Like going to live site from local version?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if your hyperlinks are linking to the right pages. Maybe you renamed your pages? Make sure you run the right, changed, index.html from the right direction in your browser, not the old version.